# status 501 and statusText Not Implemented on uploading video file to AWS S3 using pre signed url using node js fetch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fetch-api, pre-signed-url

I want to upload video file to S3 using pre signed url. But I am getting
`status: 501, statusText: 'Not Implemented'`.

I tried to get help from other similar question on stackovderflow and tried setting content type and content length but still getting same error.

Here is code by which I generated pre signed url

```js
var S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3')

async function getS3UploadSignedUrl() {
    var s3 = new S3({
        accessKeyId: config.aws.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: config.aws.secretAccessKey,
        region: config.aws.region,
        apiVersion: '2010-12-01'
    });
    
    let params = {
        Bucket: config.aws.s3Bucket,
        Key: 'myVideo.mp4',
        Expires: 60 * 60, // in seconds
        ContentType: 'video/mp4',
        ACL: 'public-read',
    }
    let signedUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
    console.log('signedUrl', signedUrl)
}
```

I am trying to upload using this code

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const FILE_PATH = '/home/alok/Downloads/video.mp4';
const signedUrl = 'https://my pre signed url'

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(FILE_PATH);
const contentLength = fs.statSync(FILE_PATH).size;

async function uploader() {
    var options = {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "content-type": "video/mp4" },
        body: fileStream,
        'Content-Length': contentLength
    }
    let response = await fetch(signedUrl, options)
    console.log(response)
}

uploader()
```

My bucket Bucket policy

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) details

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

What I am missing so not able to uplad video?

Answer (score 1):

[fetch](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html#fetch) might require some extra configuration for uploading file. Its working file with [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro)

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('/home/alok/Downloads/video.mp4');

let signedUrl = 'https://my pre signed url'

axios.put(signedUrl, fileContent, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
    }
})
    .then(response => {
        console.log('File uploaded successfully!', response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is working fine

```html
<html>

<body>
    <script>
        let url = "https://my pre signed url";

        async function handleForm(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const form = event.target;
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            const file = formData.get("myFile");
            console.log("my file", file);

            let options = {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' },
                body: file
            };
            let response = await fetch(url, options);
            console.log('response', response)
        }
    </script>

    <form onSubmit="handleForm(event)">
        <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```